# how to query records which value is not reducing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Given a sample table

```
Field 1 | Field 2    | Field 3
------------------------------
class1  | 02-09-2016 | 10.00
Class1  | 03-09-2016 | 09.20
Class1  | 04-09-2016 | 08.00
class2  | 02-09-2016 | 10.00
Class2  | 03-09-2016 | 10.00
Class2  | 04-09-2016 | 10.00
class3  | 02-09-2016 | 33.32
Class3  | 03-09-2016 | 40.12
Class3  | 04-09-2016 | 10.20
```

I want to query the Field1 for which Field3 is not changing for a period of time. In this case, I need to select only class2 for which Field3 is not changing between 02-09-2016 & 04-09-2016.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table setup:

```
create table so1 (field1 varchar2(100), field2 varchar2(100), field3 varchar2(100))

insert into so1
  select *
    from (
        select 'class1', '02-09-2016', '10.00' from dual union all
        select 'Class1', '03-09-2016', '09.20'  from dual union all
        select 'Class1', '04-09-2016', '08.00'  from dual union all
        select 'class2', '02-09-2016', '10.00'  from dual union all
        select 'Class2', '03-09-2016', '10.00'  from dual union all
        select 'Class2', '04-09-2016', '10.00'  from dual union all
        select 'class3', '02-09-2016', '33.32'  from dual union all
        select 'Class3', '03-09-2016', '40.12'  from dual union all
        select 'Class3', '04-09-2016', '10.20'  from dual 
     )
```

Query:

```
select field1, field2, field3
  from (
         select s.*, 
                count(distinct field3) over (partition by upper(field1)) cnt
           from so1 s
       ) 
 where cnt = 1
```

The query selects all rows/columns meeting the criteria.

Comment: I used the below query to get the results. it is working for me. Select Field1,count(distinct Field3) cnt from sol s group by field1 having count(field3) = 1 and count(distinct field2) > 1. Second condition to avoid single row fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just look at the `min()` and `max()` values and compare them:

```
select field1
from t
group by field1
having min(field3) = max(field3);
```

Comment: I want to exclude the Field1 even one Field3 is different and I want to select only if all Field3 values are not changing between any date range..

Comment: @Boopathi . . . That is what this query does.  You might need a `where` clause to specify the date range.

Answer (score 0):

then all you want is to find the field1 where there is onlyh one distinct value of field3 ?

that is done with a grouping and a Having clause

```
 Select Distinct field1 from table t
 Where not exists
    (Select * from table 
     where field1 = t.field1
     having count(distinct field3) > 1)
```